# How to solve this exponential equation with the given $n$?

Tags: exponential-function

How to solve this exponential equation:

$$n2^n=2^{37}\ ?$$

My answer is $n=32$. Is my answer correct?
\begin{align}
n2^n &= 2^{37} \\
\implies 2^{37} &= 2^5 2^{32} = 32 \cdot 2^{32} \\
\implies n &= 32
\end{align}

Comment: please show your efforts...

Comment: @Vikrant Desai , added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not. You have a minor mistake.

$2^{37} = 2^5 \cdot 2^{32}$

Not $2^5 + 2^{32}.$

---

### Solution -

\begin{align}
n \times 2^n &= 2^{37} \\
n \times 2^n &= 2^5 \times 2^{32} \\
n \times 2^n &= 32 \times 2^{32}.
\end{align}
So $n = 32$.

Comment: Oops yeah it was a typo , thanks

Comment: If its typo. Your solution and answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$n\cdot 2^n=2^{37}.$$ Write your equation in the form $$n\cdot 2^n=2^{32}\cdot 2^5$$ and from here we get your solution $$n=32.$$